# Is it possible to add a reference to an asmx web service of a web site without redeploying?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

We have a legacy ASP.NET web site (not web application, so I can freely edit the code) where I'm pretty sure that the live code doesn't match the version we have in source control.

I have to make a small change where I move the logic of a method to a webservice.

So the old method was something like:

```
public byte[] CreatePivot(DataTable D, string PivotPath, string Parms)
{
 ...LOGIC!
}
```

The new method is going to be something like:

```
public byte[] CreatePivot(DataTable D, string PivotPath, string Params)
{
       ConsoleApplication4.PivotService.Service1 pivotService = new ConsoleApplication4.PivotService.Service1();
       byte[] bob = pivotService.CreatePivot(D, PivotPath, Params);
}
```

When referencing the new service the following is added to the web.config...

```
<applicationSettings>
        <ConsoleApplication4.Properties.Settings>
            <setting name="ConsoleApplication4_PivotService_Service1" serializeAs="String">
                <value>http://aservice.com/PivotWebservice.asmx</value>
            </setting>
        </ConsoleApplication4.Properties.Settings>
    </applicationSettings>
```

Is it possible to add a reference to the new service without redeploying? Is the only needed change the addition to the web.config or is there something more to it?

**Edit:**

I see that there is a App_Webreferences folder in the directory of the live site with a folder for each web service. This folder has a .disco, discomap and .wsdl file in it. Maybe it'll work if I copy those files across too.

Comment: Why don't you simply take a day to synchronize the sources, and then take two days to change your company's procedures for deploying websites? What if your backup (do you have any?) gets corrupted (which often won't be noticed until it's too late) and your server crashes? Then you can't place the working code back! And when you have solved these problems, you can simply add the service reference locally, test it, and then deploy the site to your live server. There is no other sensible way of doing this.

Comment: And please tell us more about your environment so we can judge whether we'd be giving you a rope to hang yourself with.

Comment: @CodeCaster I ended up copying the web site, converting it to a web app and readding it to TFS...of course this was my intention in the end. The only reason I asked is because it was an urgent production bug. I was also curious if it was possible.

Comment: @JohnSaunders Pretend I didn't mention the editing live code part and was just curious if it was possible. We don't all get to work in companies with automated builds and flawless deployment procedures. Unfortunately editing live code is the way things have been done here in the past. I am in the process of converting all our web sites to web apps, adding them to TFS, setting up automated builds, introducing proper deployment procedures etc but this app hasn't seen that love yet and the production bug takes precedence.

Comment: @woggles: one of my responsibilities at work is to take out applications, including the legacy applications, and bring them into TFS, with automated builds and deploys, and good practices, and all other ALM goodness. We're only starting. But not since 1995 have I edited production code on a production server. There's no excuse for that in 2011. None. That's not a matter of being cutting edge, it's simply unprofessional to do what you're doing.

Comment: @JohnSaunders ok well if that's unprofessional I'll do it properly and deploy the app in 4 days time while our company loses millions of dollars of business because no one can produce financial reports and they move their business elsewhere

Comment: Why in the world would it take you four days??? And how do you know that your fix works?

Comment: @johnsaunders copying the code into tfs, converting to web app if possible (not possible if there is a mix of vb and cs code), deploying to test, staging, complete functionality testing and deploying to live would take that long. I completely get where you are coming from and agree with you about the deployment procedures but the question wasn't about that. maybe it would have been better to ask something along the lines of what happens when you add a web reference to a project...

Comment: Please update your question to make it clear that neither the production code, nor your "local source" are in a source control system. I think a good deal of my reaction was based on the assumption that you even _have_ source control. Talking about TFS and deployments didn't help make that more clear. I guess I read "local source" and didn't want to believe you really just meant some files on disk.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So, to recap, your production site doesn't match your "local source". Are you using source control? Doesn't sound like it.

In any case, you want to do software development in your production site, right? Just edit and go, no testing, no "deployment"?

Yeah, you can do that. It's your choice.

Comment: I suggest that you go through the question again and look for the '?', then read the bit before it and tell me if your answer actually answers their question.

Comment: @Justin In case you haven't read it: he wants to do this, because he's not sure his live code matches his development code. That's simply an unacceptable disaster which should be solved first. What do you have to do then? Just post a comment? :-)

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes! The guy has a specific question that John has made no attempt to answer.  When you have to paraphrase a question into a completely different one in order to make your answer fit its usually a bad sign.  If he said "no you can't do this, you should ...", or "yes you can do this but you should do this instead ..." that would have been fine as it actually answers the question **as well** as providing useful advice.

Comment: @Justin: it would be unprofessional, and conceivably criminal, for me to help this person destroy his production systems without knowing a lot more about the situation. You're assuming, for instance, that because he asked this question, that he's aware of the potential consequences, and even that he's authorized to make source code changes on the production server. No way!

Comment: "Give a man a fish, and you feed him for a day. Give him a gun and no firearms training, and if he shoots himself in the head, it's not your fault". Not me.

Comment: How is that different from any other question?  The terms of service protect users against liability and it would be kind of boring to have to prefix every answer with "are you authorized to make source code changes?"

Comment: Did you get that he's talking about changing the code on his production site? It's a "web site", not a "web application project", so he's talking about editing the actual code that is actually running in production. He's not talking about making source code changes on his desktop then deploying to Production, possibly after testing.

Comment: But if he gave us some context like, "the application won't be in use again until December", that would give us a clue about how large a disaster it would be if, for instance, he removed the code he showed us and replaced it with a web service call, before the web service exists.

Comment: @JohnSaunders this was an urgent production bug that needed fixing asap. Of course we have source control but I dont trust what's in there for this specific app. I do realise its extremely bad practice to just edit and go but that's all I had to work with hence the question.

Comment: I would never consider what you did to be a fix. Did you even _test_ it? What makes you think you haven't made the problem worse? How will you maintain that when your source control doesn't match what's in production? It's a matter of ignoring the facts so that you can think you have "fixed" something.

Comment: Look, I just got through fixing a critical production problem. It required a single-character change, since the problem was that the code was redirecting to the wrong URL. I can conceive of making such a change in production (changing "Test" to "Test2"). No way I would consider something as serious as refactoring a block of code into a web service, and all without automated unit testing, or testing in a QA environment before release, or anything other than prayer.